# How to a collapse other menus when click on radio buttons in bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have some bootstrap `radio buttons` that each have their own collapsible content, I can click on them and they expand but each time I expand one the other one should collapse which doesn't happen... make it where one I click on another radio button the other menus collapse - See example -

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- VLC Source -->
            <div class="form-group row m-1">
                <div class="form-check col-lg-6" id="myGroup">
                    <input class="form-check-input collapsed" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="vlcRadio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vlc" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vlc" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >VLC Source</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- VLC Source Form -->
            <div id="vlc" class="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup">
                <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                    <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Width</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1920" /> 
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                    <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Height</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1080" /> 
                </div>
               <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                    <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Type</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="VLC Source" /> 
                </div> 
                <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                   <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">URL</label>
                    <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                </div> 
                 <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                   <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Volume</label>
                 <form class="range-field col-lg-8">
                   <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="100" step="1" id="customRange3">
                 </form>
                </div> 
            </div>
            
            <!-- VNC Source -->
                <div class="form-group row m-1">
                <div class="form-check ">
                    <input class="form-check-input collapsed" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vnc" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vnc" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" >VNC Viewer</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- VNC Source Form -->
            <div id="vnc" class="collapse" >
                <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                    <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Type</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1920" /> 
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
                    <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">VNC Server</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1080" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
                      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get desired effect by `jQuery`'s custom function `.collapse()`.

**Codepen Example:** https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/mdrMgKZ

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$('.form-check-input').click(function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('#' + $(this).attr('aria-controls')).collapse('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- VLC Source -->
    <div class="form-group row m-1">
        <div class="form-check col-lg-6" id="myGroup">
            <input class="form-check-input collapsed" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="vlcRadio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vlc" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vlc" >
            <label class="form-check-label" >VLC Source</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- VLC Source Form -->
    <div id="vlc" class="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup">
        <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
            <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Width</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1920" /> 
        </div>
        <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
            <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Height</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1080" /> 
        </div>
       <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
            <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Type</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="VLC Source" /> 
        </div> 
        <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
           <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">URL</label>
            <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
        </div> 
         <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
           <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Volume</label>
         <form class="range-field col-lg-8">
           <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="100" step="1" id="customRange3">
         </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
            
    <!-- VNC Source -->
    <div class="form-group row m-1">
        <div class="form-check ">
            <input class="form-check-input collapsed" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vnc" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vnc" >
            <label class="form-check-label" >VNC Viewer</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- VNC Source Form -->
    <div id="vnc" class="collapse" >
        <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
            <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Type</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1920" /> 
        </div>
        <div  class="form-group row m-1 ">
            <label  class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">VNC Server</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" required value="1080" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Code summary:** Whenever `click` event occurred, get the current `aria-controls` attribute value and hide everyone else except clicked one.

Comment: Glad, this resolved your issue @CodingNoob ! Mark it as accepted answer, if that's what you wanted.